# Migrating web site to web application in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem to migrating web site to a web application. The problem is even if I added namespaces to user-defined classes, code-behind files of user controls dont see them. So it gives an error like

```
    Error   1   The type or namespace name 'CustomMasterPage' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    G:\Test.NET\Test\Test.Web\Test.Web\Test.Web.Admin.UI\MasterPages\PopUp.master.cs
    8   42  Test.Web.Admin.UI
```

If I added all the user-defined classes again, by using add new item, then it works fine. But I dont want to do this for all classes manually.

Comment: Web Site has all custom classes in `App_Code` folder, did you include this folder in your Web Application?

Comment: @AmarPalsapure I have already did that. But it doesnt work.

Comment: `Add Existing Item` ? Check the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [following guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx). Make sure you have rigorously followed all the steps.